# Создание клона с обработчиком события

Tags: c#, mvvm

Можно ли создать клон объекта, c присоединенным обработчиком события, при реализации интерфейса `IClonable`. Например:

```
public class A : IClonable, //INPC
{
     //...
}
public class B : IClonable
{
    public A PropA { get; set; }
    public B()
    {
        PropA.PropertyChanged += a_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void a_PropertyChanged()
    {
        //...
    }
    public object Clone()
    {

        // ????
        return new B() { PropA = this.PropA.Clone() };
    }

}
```

В данном случае в созданном клоне `B` нет подписки на событие.
Есть ли более удобный вариант, чем подписываться заново в новом объекте на событие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот эта конструкция не должна работать ни в клоне, ни в оригинальном объекте:

```
public A PropA { get; set; }
public B()
{
  PropA.PropertyChanged += a_PropertyChanged;
}
```

На момент вызова конструктора в свойстве `PropA` еще лежит `null` - поэтому подписаться на событие невозможно.

В реальности вы, видимо, используете другой конструктор для создания объекта B - потому все и работает. А вот при клонировании перестает.

Исправить ситуацию можно двумя способами.

### Способ первый.

Свойство следует сделать неизменяемым, чтобы исключить случайное присвоение значения вне конструктора (все равно правильно это присвоение работать не будет):

```
public A PropA { get; }
public B (A argA)
{
  PropA = argA;
  PropA.PropertyChanged += a_PropertyChanged;
}
```

При клонировании объекта надо воспользоваться тем же самым конструктором что и при создании.

### Способ второй.

Подписку на событие следует делать в мутаторе свойства:

```
private A fieldA;
public A PropA 
{ 
  get { return fieldA; }
  set
  {
    if (fieldA != null) fieldA.PropertyChanged -= a_PropertyChanged;
    fieldA = value;
    if (fieldA != null) fieldA.PropertyChanged += a_PropertyChanged;
  }
}
```

В таком случае объект будет B слушать события со "связанного" объекта A независимо от того, кто и сколько раз переустанавливал ему PropA.

Answer (score -1):

В классе `A` нужно в функции `Clone()` дописать, чтобы обработчики событий тоже переприсвоились:

```
class A: IClonable 
{
        public object Clone()
        {
            A tt = new A();
            tt.PropertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            return tt;
        }
}
```

Comment: Это передаст событие в оригинальный объект B, а не в его клон.

Comment: Конструкция не верна, `PropertyChanged` может может находиться только в левой части -= или +=.